# How to create multiple entries of same field?

Tags: django-models

model.py:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    #4 fields of type CharFieldvalues excepted from a user. 

class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I create multiple entries of `field1`. The number of `field1` could be 1 or 2 or more for each `Model2` instance.

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple instances of field4". Perhaps you can illustrate your problem with an example?

Comment: Although I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, my first guess is that you want to link multiple `Model2`s to the same `Model1`. You can do that by turning the `OneToOneField` in a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: With ```ForeignKey``` I will have to first make instances of Model1 and then add only one of Model1 instance to field4. I want multiple field4 not predefined.

Comment: Does a `ManyToManyField` work for your case?